# Ist "unter lauter Freunden" richtig?

Tags: idiom, grammatical-case

Was bedeutet *lauter*?
Wird nach *unter* hier Genitiv oder Dativ verwendet?

Comment: https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/lauter-meaning/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das sind eigentlich zwei Fragen:

Zum Fall (Genitiv / Dativ):
Im Zeifel nach der zugehörigen Frage suchen, mit der man danach fragt, hier: Unter *wem* -> also Dativ.
(das betrifft in diesem Satz allerdings nur das Wort "Freunden")

"lauter" dagegen ist ein [**indeklinables** Adjektiv](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lauter_viel_viele), verändert also seine Form nicht. Es bedeutet in diesem Fall "ganz viele". (vgl. Emanuels Komentar)

Würde man ein anderes ("normales") Adjektiv benutzen, müßte man es anpassen, z.B. "unter *gute**n*** Freunde**n**".